# Mock error response in combine to test error handling

Tags: swift

I have a  service mock setup, but i want to be able to set it up to return an error so i can test that scenario too

```
class PostsServiceMock: PostsServiceProtocol {

  var posts: [Post] = [.mock()]

  var getPostsCallCount = 0

  func getPosts() -> AnyPublisher<[Post], APIError> {

    getPostsCallCount += 1

    return Just(posts)
      .setFailureType(to: APIError.self)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }

  func reset() {
    getPostsCallCount = 0
  }
}
```

How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

```
class PostsServiceMock: PostsServiceProtocol {

  var posts: [Post] = [.mock()]
  var getPostsCallCount = 0
  var shouldReturnError = false

  func getPosts() -> AnyPublisher<[Post], APIError> {

    getPostsCallCount += 1

    if shouldReturnError {
      return Fail(error: APIError.server(""))
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
      return Just(posts)
        .setFailureType(to: APIError.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
  }

  func reset() {
    getPostsCallCount = 0
    shouldReturnError = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with what you did to solve the problem, not just the code.